# Sonarqube does not find junit reports

Tags: php, jenkins, sonarqube, phpunit

I am trying to publish in sonarqube the junit reports generated by phpunit.
It does'nt matter the path that I put, It never finds the files. The log show this message:No PHPUnit test report provided (see 'sonar.php.tests.reportPath' property)

My configs are the following:

```
sonar.projectKey=MyProj
sonar.projectName=MyProj
sonar.language=php
sonar.sources=Application
sonar.tests=Tests
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=build/logs/
sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=build/coverage
```

Comment: Are you sure that at this stage `build/logs/` have .xml report files ? "Logs" doesn't sound like a path for reports.

Comment: Can you provide the full logs of the analysis?

Comment: WARN: PHPUnit xml test report not found: build/logs/junit.xml
WARN: PHPUnit xml unit test coverage report not found: build/logs/clover.xml

Answer (score 1):

`sonar.php.coverage.reportPath` and `sonar.php.tests.reportPath` should provide xml file paths, not folder paths.
For example, it could be:

```
sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=reports/phpunit.coverage.xml
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=reports/phpunit.xml
```

Comment: I am creating the unit tests using this config (phpunit.config):
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="../build/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="../build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-xml" target="../build/logs/coverage"/>
        <log type="junit" target="../build/logs/junit.xml"/>
    </logging>

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the help!

I was checking the configs, and then I changed the paths from relative path to absolute paths and it is working now! The relative paths doesn't work.

By the way, now I am facing the following issue:

```
INFO: Analyzing PHPUnit coverage report: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/build/logs/clover.xml
WARN: Could not resolve 1001 file paths in clover.xml, first unresolved path: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/Application/Controller/API.php
```

I checked the clover.xml file, and the paths seems ok, the paths are absolute but sonar can't find the files:

```
<file name="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/Application/Controller/API.php">
```

Any ideas about it?

Comment: Because of your configuration "sonar.sources=Application", only "<file>" with a path starting by "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/Application" will have their coverage sent to SonarQube. In your "clover.xml", how many path does not start with "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/Application" ? 1001 ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AlbanA.-SonarSourceTeam !

All the paths starts with "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProj/Application", just like the example that I mentioned before.